# Find control of child gridview in a dropdown selected index change event

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a two gridview Gv1 which is parent and gv2 which is nested inside Gv1
and i want to find the control of child gridview as well as the label which is placed inside the itemtemplate of childgridview in the selectedindexchange of dropdownlist which is placed outside the both grids

i have used this code inside the dropdown selected index change

```
 GridView grid_child = grv_parent.FindControl("grv") as GridView;

                if (grid_child != null)
                {
                    Label lbl_asset_type = (Label)grid_child.FindControl("lbl_asset_type");
```

Comment: Assuming that your parent grid has 100 rows and each child grid has 10 rows. Which child grid and which label do you want to have? This question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a label with the ID "lbl_asset_type", which is inside a child grid inside a parent grid. There might be syntactical errors but try something like this (I haven't tested the code, but this should give you a general idea):

```
GridView grid_child = grv_parent.FindControl("grv") as GridView;

if (grid_child != null)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grid_child.Rows)
    {
         Label lblAssetType = (Label)grid_child.FindControl("lbl_asset_type");
         //Use label here. Make sure to do a null check first
    }
}
```